# Same post for review in First Posts and Late Answers

Tags: bug, reviewing

I just reviewed the same post in both [*First Posts*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/36850) and [*Late Answers*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/36851).

Does this happen to any late answer posted by a new user?

Comment: Yes, all late answers go into the review queue, and all first posts go into the first post queue. It is theoretically possible for a single post to be a user's first post, be a late answer, be marked as low quality, AND have a suggested edit on it at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, this is by design.**

Every time a new user (0 posts) makes their first post here, it goes into the First Posts review queue.

Every time a low-rep user (<50 rep) answers an old post, it goes into the Late Answers review queue.

The rest is a matter of Venn diagrams and non-empty intersections.